# Space dependent diffusion in fipy

Tags: python, fipy

I'm using fipy to model the linearized [Poisson-Boltzmann equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson%E2%80%93Boltzmann_equation), which is essentially

[image]

I'll assume I can model `f(x)` as a boundary condition. If `epsilon(x)` is a constant, fipy can handle this:

```
phi = CellVariable(mesh)

dielectric_solvent = 80.0
dielectric_inner   = 4.0

LHS = (DiffusionTerm(coeff = dielectric_solvent))
RHS = phi
eq = LHS == RHS

dr = np.linalg.norm(mesh.faceCenters, axis=0)
mask = (dr<.5) * mesh.exteriorFaces
phi.constrain(1, mask)

mask = (dr>.5) * mesh.exteriorFaces
phi.constrain(0, mask)   

sol = eq.solve(var=phi)
```

giving:

[image]

The [complete minimal example is posted as a gist](https://gist.github.com/thoppe/10304061), to keep things short this is the relevant portion.

What I'd like to do is let `epsilon(x)` vary as a function in *space*, but `DiffusionTerm` can only take a constant. How can I implement the spatially varying dielectric term?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any coefficient in FiPy can be a function of space. For example, you can set the diffusion coefficient as follows,

```
diffusion_coefficient = dielectric_solvent * ((mesh.x > -0.5) & (mesh.x < 0.5))
```

and then use that directly in your equation

```
LHS = (DiffusionTerm(coeff = diffusion_coefficient))
```

Just define your spatially varying functions using the cell centers, `mesh.x` and `mesh.y`.

Another pointer, it might be better to change your equation to

```
eq = TransientTerm() == DiffusionTerm(diffusion_coefficient) - ImplicitSourceTerm(phi)
```

so that

- the variable `phi` is solved implicitly in one sweep
- adding in a `TransientTerm` stabilizes the problem for me, just use a very large time step to approximate a steady state problem

See [my comment on your gist](https://gist.github.com/thoppe/10304061#comment-1209445) for the changes.